# How to make service tags works in security groups? Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-api-management

I'm using a Virtual Machine with a nodejs server listening in port 3000. I want to expose that server using Api Management. I tried to create a security group and just allow inbound traffic from my Api Management but it doesn't work.

I'm using Security Groups and service tags for specifying my Api Management service but the endpoint gives me a 500 error.
If i use the public ip of my Api Management service it actually works but i need to make service tags work.

I expect service tags to actually bind my api management to the security group policy, but i'm getting a 500.

Comment: Could you share some screenshots / templates or script with your Network Security Group / VNet / API Management configurations ?

Comment: Look at this: https://ibb.co/VtC0Cy8

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstood of ApiManagement service tag.

You can check the IPs in the ApiManagement service in official JSON: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

ApiManagement service tag describes source IPs of ApiManagement Control Plane service. So, when you manage configurations on ApiManagement of portal, the Azure Resource Manager will connect to your Api Management on port 3443 to apply a configuration with the source IP from ApiManagement service tag list.

That is for traffic between Internet <-> ApiManagement, so you can restrict management endpoint only to Azure / your datacenter.

In your case, between ApiManagement <-> Backend, you must use Public IP for External configuration and Private IP for internal configuration to restrict the traffic for your nodejs backend.

Few links on this topic:

- [How can I secure the connection between the API Management gateway and my back-end services?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq#how-can-i-secure-the-connection-between-the-api-management-gateway-and-my-back-end-services)
- [IP addresses of Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-ip-addresses)
- [Using Azure API Management service with an internal virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet#-creating-an-api-management-in-an-internal-virtual-network)